# Java: Math condition

Tags: java, math, conditional-statements

Is there a simple way to do this

```
if (1 < x && x < 3) { .... }
```

I want something like this:

```
if (1 < x < 3) { .... }
```

I know that the code above is wrong but....

Thanks

Comment: Python vs Java: 1-0

Comment: It is not worth to make the syntax more complicated for this, just get over it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do that in Java. You can, however, create a class, say `MathUtils`, with a `isBetween` method, like so:

```
public static boolean isBetween(int n, int begin, int end) {
  return n > begin && n < end;
}
```

Then, you could use (assuming you `import static`):

```
if (isBetween(x, 1, 3)) {
  // ...
}
```

But this would only be helpful if you have many *range* conditions.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're talking about integers:

```
if ( x == 2 ) { .... }
```

---

There's quite a few little bits of Java which come from it being a better C++ - in C or C++, there's an automatic conversion between boolean values and integers, so in C++:

```
int x = 5;

std::cout << std::boolalpha;

std::cout << ( 1 < x < 3 ) << std::endl;
std::cout << ( ( 1 < x ) < 3 ) << std::endl;
```

will print "true" twice, as `( 1 < x )` evaluates as 1 and 1 is less than 3. Java concentrates on fixing this ambiguity with parsing two binary operators by making boolean and integer types non-convertible so you have to join them with another operator; other languages don't try and fix C++ but have more complicated parsing rules so that _ < _ < _ is a ternary operator which does the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

Not using the language builtins; you'd need to go with your first answer.

Several libraries will let you do something like the following:

```
Range range = new ExclusiveRange(1,3);
if (range.contains(x)) { ... }
```

Comment: (or efficiency, for that matter)

Comment: True on both counts. :-)  For the simple situation the OP presented, it would definitely be better just to go with the pair of native comparisons.  But in more complex situations being able to pass a Range object around, instead of a pair of ints, may actually be cleaner and *more* readable (imagine adding either option to a method signature that already takes 6 `int` parameters...).

Answer (score 3):

In terms of efficiency, `(1 < x && x < 3)` is as good as you will get. To put an integer in a range, you need to do two comparisons.

If you want to make your code more readable and you have a lot of these ranges, you may want to consider creating an Interval class with a contains() function.

Answer (score 3):

You've got the simplest form in terms of straight Java syntax. You could introduce a method if you wanted:

```
public static boolean isBetween(int x, int min, int max) {
    return min < x && x < max;
}
```

then call it with:

```
if (isBetween(x, 1, 3))
```

but I don't think that's really any clearer - and it means there's more possibility of putting the arguments in the wrong order. The `Range` class suggested in another answer would alleviate that concern, but at the price of adding even more clutter...

Answer (score 1):

Thate statement using `&&` is the simplest you can get. Java, nor any other C-style language I know, has support for chained inequalities.